# Sphinx-quickstart aborts after asking about "Separate source and build directories"

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have inherited a project containing sphinx-quickstart generated artifacts under a `docs` directory.  Some of the contents have changed and I would like to rebuild them.

I used

```
  sphinx-quickstart
```

It was not a pretty result..  Note from below: I tried both options (y and n) in response to

> Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]:

[image]

Comment: You should include the error message as text in the question instead of only posting a picture of it. That way it shows in search, others can find and copy it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sphinx-quickstart`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html) is a tool for setting up your project's documentation. It is not intended to be used for updating or maintenance of documentation.

Assuming you have set up a Python virtual environment, activated the virtual environment, and installed the requirements to build your documentation, you should be able to rebuild documentation using `make <builder>` where `<builder>` is the format of the documentation you want to build.  For example, while in the same directory as your documentation's `conf.py` file, issue the command `make html`. See also [documentation of `sphinx-build`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html).